# Facebook comment plugin problem in blogger website

Tags: html

I am using Facebook comment plugin in my blogger site, and want to split it into two pages ([Desktop](https://www.etihashnama.com/2020/07/christian-ronaldo-w-tahmeed.html) and [Mobile](https://www.etihashnama.com/2020/07/christian-ronaldo-w-tahmeed.html?m=1)).

Because the links are different, the Facebook comment plugin has two separate comment sections instead of just one.

Is there a way to combine the comment sections into one?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<h2>Comment with Facebook</h2>
<div class='fb-comments'> data-numposts=&#39;5&#39; data-width=&quot;100%&quot;&#160; expr:href=&#39;data:post.canonicalUrl&#39; expr:title=&#39;data:post.title&#39; expr:xid=&#39;data:post.id&#39;</div>
</b:if>
```

Comment: How can anyone say, without knowing what "my fb plugin" is? Which plugin is it? Downloaded from where?

Comment: sorry man.I didn't pay heed to that....I added that

Comment: You should check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

Answer (score 0):

You can either

- disable mobile view from theme settings (recommended)
- replace `data:post.canonicalUrl` to `data:post.canonicalUrl params {m: 1}`